# How to import the CMS content in CSV file

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, import, csv

I want to import the CMS content in to .csv file. So can anyone has used any tool to import the CMS content.

Answer (score 1):

There are many custom extensions available to import/export CMS pages and CMS static blocks.

Few of those extensions are listed below:

- https://codecanyon.net/item/importexport-cms-contents/18886218
- https://marketplace.magento.com/commerceextensions-ext6883.html

Above extensions are for importing CMS pages and CMS blocks content both.

Specific extensions are also available.

**Import content of only CMS pages:**

- https://marketplace.magento.com/magebees-import-export-cms-pages.html

**Import content of only CMS Static Blocks:**

- https://marketplace.magento.com/magebees-import-export-cms-blocks.html

**Update:** If you are a developer and you are able to import via SQL, then you can try below solution.

- http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/export-import-cms-pages-static-blocks-via-ssh/

Comment: I have seen all the extensions but all are paid versions. Is there any free extensions to Import the CMS content.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no free extension available. If you are a developer, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following script.
CMS Pages

```
function getCmspages() {

$pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();

foreach ($pages as $page) {

    echo 'Page Id : '.$page->getId().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Page Title : '.$page->getTitle().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Page Identifier : '.$page->getIdentifier().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Page Template : '.$page->getRootTemplate().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Meta Keywords : '.$page->getMetaKeywords().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Meta Desc : '.$page->getMetaDescription().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Content Heading : '.$page->getContentHeading().PHP_EOL;
    echo'Content : '.$page->getContent().PHP_EOL;
    echo'Status : '.$page->getIsActive().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Layout Update Xml : '.$page->getLayoutUpdateXml().PHP_EOL;
    $storeIds= $page->getResource()->lookupStoreIds($page->getId());

    foreach($storeIds as $storeId){

        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId);
        echo 'Store Name : '. $store->getName().PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Code : '. $store->getCode().PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Website Id : '. $store->getWebsiteId().PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Group Id : '. $store->getGroupId().PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Sort Order : '. $store->getSortOrder().PHP_EOL;

    }

    echo '-----------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

}

Static Blocks

```
 function getCmsblocks() {

$blocks = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();

echo "block here".PHP_EOL;

foreach ($blocks as $block) {

    echo 'Id : '.$block->getId().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Title : '.$block->getTitle().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Identifier : '.$block->getIdentifier().PHP_EOL;
    echo'Content : '.$block->getContent().PHP_EOL;
    echo'Status : '.$block->getIsActive().PHP_EOL;
    $storeIds= $block->getResource()->lookupStoreIds($block->getId());

    foreach($storeIds as $storeId){

        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId);
        echo 'Store Name : '. $store->getName().PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Code : '. $store->getCode().PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Website Id : '. $store->getWebsiteId().PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Group Id : '. $store->getGroupId().PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Sort Order : '. $store->getSortOrder().PHP_EOL;
        echo '-----------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '-----------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

}

For full code please refer my tutorial.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/export-static-blocks-magento/